# Why this function not getting called?

Tags: matlab

```
%% ----------Chua.m----------
function out = chua(t,in)
x = in(1);
y = in(2);
z = in(3);
alpha  = 15.6;
beta   = 28; 
m0     = -1.143;
m1     = -0.714;
h = m1*x+0.5*(m0-m1)*(abs(x+1)-abs(x-1));
xdot = alpha*(y-x-h);
ydot = x - y+ z;
zdot  = -beta*y;
out = [xdot ydot zdot]';
end

% ----------StartChua.m----------
% [t,y] = ode45(@Chua,[0 100],[0.7 0 0]);
% plot3(y(:,1),y(:,2),y(:,3))
% grid
```

Everytime when I use `[t,y] = ode45(@Chua,[0 100],[0.7 0 0]);` I get an error:

```
Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 115)
  odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);
```

Also in the code it tells me, the function might be unused. I dont get it, this code should work.
I am on the right path, that I know, also I am not using anthing that can't be compiled.

Comment: Is this really the full error message? I see no reason stated in it. Usually MATLAB specified what the error is, not just where it happens.

Comment: Well it just says at the start: Attempt to execute SCRIPT Chua as a function: C:/..../Chua.m

Comment: Well, that explains it. Does the file it tries to run match the one you show here? Do you have any other commands above the `function` declaration in that file?

Comment: It appears that your file is named `Chua.m`, but the function is `chua`. MATLAB is case-sensitive. I suggest changing the function name to `Chua`.